# Using np.where to return the mean of df row's based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause, np

Let's suppose I have this following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flag = pd.DataFrame({'flag': [ [], ['red'], ['red, green'], ['red, blue'], ['blue'] ]})
colors_values = pd.DataFrame({'red': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'green': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'blue': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]})
```

[image]
[image]

I have a 1D df called 'flag' that each row contains a list of colors (red, green, blue) and another df 'colors_values' with these colors names. They have the same number of rows.

My goal is to use np.where to return the mean of the values for each row of 'colors_values' based on 'flag'. The output would be something like this:

[image]

If there is a better/faster way to do it instead of using np.where, I'd like to know.

Comment: why only with np where?

Comment: So, in reality it's part of a code that I'm making that contains a huge amount of data and I was using a for loop to do it. I heard that using np.where (vectorizing data) is way faster so I was wondering if doing that way would improve performance

Comment: You have this in your df `['red, green']`is that correct or should it actually be: ` ['red', 'green']`

Comment: You're right! My mistake, it should be ['red', 'green'], yes. Each row a list of names

Answer (score 2):

##### Fast solution

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

# encode the colors into indicator variables
mask = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(flag['flag'])

# mask the color values where indicator is zero then calculate mean
result = colors_values.sort_index(axis=1).mask(mask == 0).mean(axis=1)
```

##### Result

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.5
3    2.5
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas merge is pretty fast, if you allow of bit of a ramp up time you could do a merge/groupby:

```
df_flag = flag.explode('flag').reset_index()
df_colors = colors_values.reset_index().melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='flag').reset_index()
df_flag = df_flag.merge(df_colors, on=['index', 'flag'], how='left')

df_grouped = df_flag.groupby(['index'])['value'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange color names matching between dataframes as shown below:

```
means = colors_values.apply(lambda x: x[flag.iloc[x.name][0]].mean(), axis=1)
```

---

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.5
3    2.5
4    4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `str.get_dummies()` and multiply by the `color_values` df

```
(flag['flag']
.str[0]
.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
.mul(colors_values)
.where(lambda x: x.ne(0))
.mean(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.5
3    2.5
4    4.0
```